# Can someone translate this Godot 2 code to Godot 3?

Tags: godot, gdscript

```
if is_colliding():
   var normal = getcollisionnormal()
   var object = get_collider()
   var objectParent = object.get_parent()
   if normal == Vector2(0, 1):
      objectParent.queue_free()`
```

I’m using move_and_slide to move if that helps.

Comment: Did you try google translate!? :P Sorry,  StackOverflow is not for translating code. That looks simple enough, look up each method call and see if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

The most up to date information for physics (including collisions) can be found here:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html

The documenation for nodes is here:https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_node.html

Aparrently get_parent() is not advisable. Someone else had a similar issue here:
https://godotengine.org/qa/9459/how-to-call-a-special-func-from-another-node-above